# SSH fix in headless mode

Tags: pi-3, ssh, headless

So I have a brand new RasPi 3, and I'm having SSH trouble. Yes, I have enabled SSH.

My problem matches exactly what is described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=177111):

> I just bought a new Raspberry Pi 3 and was not able to connect via SSH, even after creating an empty /boot/ssh file. SSH client under linux showed the following:

`$ ssh -v 192.168.0.32
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.32 [192.168.0.32] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/vlad/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vlad/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vlad/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vlad/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vlad/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vlad/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vlad/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vlad/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 192.168.0.32`

The proposed solution is to run the following `sudo` commands:

```
$ sudo rm -r /etc/ssh/ssh*key
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`
```

My question is whether there is any chance to apply this fix, or another one, in headless mode, i.e. without keyboard and screen. I have neither in my home, just laptops.

Comment: if you have linux on one of those laptops then you should be able to do a loopback mount of the fs and repair the ssh configuration.

Comment: I have access to the card on a Ubuntu VM. How would you proceed from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## On your other Linux system:

### mount the drive, i.e:

```
sudo mkdir /b
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /b
```

### remove the old ssh host keys as in the instructions:

```
sudo rm /b/etc/ssh/ssh*key
sudo rm /b/etc/ssh/ssh*key.pub
```

### Replace the keys:

You can't run the reconfigure safely, so you could either:

- not create keys and see if the next boot detects the need to run keygen,
  or:
- clone your VM's keys to your RPi:

  sudo cp /etc/ssh/ssh*key* /b/etc/ssh/

### But remember to cleanly unmount before removing the card:

```
sudo umount /b
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Unfortunately I was so extremely frustrated in the meantime that I wiped the card and re-installed the minimal version of Raspian (which better suits my headless needs anyway). There, I got SSH to work, following the docs. So I could not test your solution. Not sure about policy of accepting here... I appreciate the help!